# Kill or stop execution of PHP script initiated by CRON?

Tags: php, cron

I have scheduled a CRON which calls/executes a PHP script every five minutes. PHP script perform following tasks

1. Checks for the flag value in database to identify if the previous run is still executing. Value of 1 in the DB tells that process is still running while a value of 0 means it is not.
2. If the flag value is 1, then exit the PHP else continue to next step.
3. Update the flag value in database from 0 to 1.
4. Execute the business logic.
5. Update the flag value back from 1 to 0, so that next CRON can executes if the data is available in user tables.

All works fine so far, depending on the size of user uploaded data the process on an average takes 35 to 40 minutes to complete.

Question, Is there anyway to kill or stop the execution of PHP script once started by cron. May be a button to let users stop the execution, upload new data and wait for CRON run. I can take care of reseting all the flags and data it's just the kill of PHP script is what i am trying to figure out.

I did some google and figured i can use some commands like:

```
Killall -9 PHP
```

to kill all php processes running on server, but not sure how to do this through PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

`ps aux |grep 'part_of_the_name_of_your_script'|awk '{print $2}' |xargs kill -9 {}`

Or in your crontab file use crun and variable `CRUN_TIME`
see `crun -h`

Comment: killer one liner, thank you.
I got error with `{}`, command worked when I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

A [lock file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) would be very appropriate for this tasks.
The PHP script can attempt to create a new file, and if none is created already you can safely know that the script is the only one running at the present time. If a file exists, you can simply exit the script.

Example:

```
<?php

if (file_exists('/var/run/my-script')) {
    exit(1); // already running
}

file_put_contents('/var/run/my-script', getmypid());

/** Business Logic **/

unlink('/var/run/my-script');
exit(0);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am not sure if this will solve the issue in hand. What you suggested is using a lock file to check if the script is already running or not. I am able to manage that already with the help of database flag (Not very efficient but working for now). What i am looking for is a way to stop the execution once the script start processing the business logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), but it might not work (or return permission denied errors) as cron processes are executed by either the current user or root, and the web server user doesn't usually have access to these processes.